# Problem in Pandas: Merging correctly & iteratively averaging whilst loading into df?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, perceptron

I have a problem with my data set that I have merged. I have two sets, of which I have to combine on a specific key identifier, called "msno". Not all values are present, and someone can be in the dataset multiple times.

**Code example**:

```
colnamesa = ['msno','date','num_25','num_50','num_75','num_985']

colnamesb = ['msno','city','bd','gender',\
             'registered_via','registration_init_time']


a = pandas.read_csv('userlogs.csv',  names= colnamesa, skiprows=[0])
b = pandas.read_csv('members.csv', names= colnamesb,skiprows=[0])
c = a.merge(b, how='outer', on ='msno')
df = c.dropna(thresh=4)`
```

**Output**

```
    msno        date  num_25  num_50  num_75  num_985  num_100  num_unq  total_secs  city    bd gender  registered_via  registration_init_time
0     u9E91QDTvHLq6NXjEaWv8u4QIqhrHk72kE+w31Gnhdg=  20170331.0     8.0     4.0     0.0      1.0     21.0     18.0    6309.273   1.0   0.0    NaN             7.0              20161220.0
1     u9E91QDTvHLq6NXjEaWv8u4QIqhrHk72kE+w31Gnhdg=  20170316.0     6.0     4.0     1.0      3.0     26.0     31.0    7926.107   1.0   0.0    NaN             7.0              20161220.0
2     u9E91QDTvHLq6NXjEaWv8u4QIqhrHk72kE+w31Gnhdg=  20170325.0     6.0     4.0     2.0      1.0     65.0     58.0   17148.343   1.0   0.0    NaN             7.0              20161220.0
3     u9E91QDTvHLq6NXjEaWv8u4QIqhrHk72kE+w31Gnhdg=  20170310.0    10.0     2.0     1.0      5.0     35.0     39.0   10519.150   1.0   0.0    NaN             7.0              20161220.0
4     u9E91QDTvHLq6NXjEaWv8u4QIqhrHk72kE+w31Gnhdg=  20170328.0   101.0     1.0     3.0      6.0     34.0     80.0   11046.850   1.0   0.0    NaN             7.0              20161220.0
5     u9E91QDTvHLq6NXjEaWv8u4QIqhrHk72kE+w31Gnhdg=  20170307.0    13.0     2.0     3.0      2.0     45.0     55.0   12581.496   1.0   0.0    NaN             7.0              20161220.0
6     u9E91QDTvHLq6NXjEaWv8u4QIqhrHk72kE+w31Gnhdg=  20170321.0    13.0     3.0     2.0      1.0     41.0     31.0   11806.946   1.0   0.0    NaN             7.0              20161220.0
7     u9E91QDTvHLq6NXjEaWv8u4QIqhrHk72kE+w31Gnhdg=  20170315.0    14.0     7.0     3.0     11.0     24.0     41.0   10153.821   1.0   0.0    NaN             7.0              20161220.0
8     u9E91QDTvHLq6NXjEaWv8u4QIqhrHk72kE+w31Gnhdg=  20170330.0     0.0     0.0     1.0      0.0     24.0      2.0    5773.754   1.0   0.0    NaN             7.0              20161220.0
```

**Desired output** 
For all of the entries with the same msno (they are the same person), I would like to average the scores in num_25,...., total_seconds, but not the date. Is this doable?

Comment: Please provide some sample of your dataframes so we can reproduce your code

Comment: Output is quite difficult to format here, but I'll provide it in the OP. @nixon

Comment: There is no attempt at the averaging here. So what is the problem? Read docs on pandas' `groupby`.

Comment: I can't understand why merge in iterative mode is so buggy. Does anyone know why? It happens so often with approximately 0.25-0.5% errors and reindexing completely screws everything up. Why is pandas so buggy. It's 100% reliable in non-iterative mode with strong typing and fails with large_memory flag set to false or true.